# Does a blocking send() returns immediately?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winapi, network-programming

I thought that calling `send()` on a blocking socket does not return until all data are sent (until the last chunk of data is sent to the send buffer that is), however the following test showed otherwise:

```
// buffer = "AAAAAAAA...B" (10 MB)
char *buffer = new char[10485760];
memset(buffer, 0x41, 10485760);
buffer[10485758] = 0x42;
buffer[10485759] = '\0';

// Send buffer
send(s, buffer, 10485760, 0) ;

printf("send() has returned");
```

So basically I connected to Netcat and sent `buffer`, and even after `send()` has returned, `AAAAAAAAAAAAAA...` was still being displayed to the console on the other end. You can close the sender at any moment and the sending would stop (so it is not that `buffer` has already arrived to the other end but it takes a long time to display it to the console).

This can only make sense if the send buffer is 10+ MB.

**Edit:** the return value of `send()` is `10485760` (i.e. `buffer` size).

Comment: You should take a look at `send`'s return value. There probably is an error code. Sockets have a maximum write size for queued data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`send` sends the data to the kernel, where it is placed in a socket buffer. If the kernel runs out of socket buffers, the `send` will block (or fail, if it is non-blocking).

That has very little to do with the kernel sending data to the network.

However, if you kill a program, all of its sockets are forcibly closed, which will discard any unsent data sitting in kernel buffers.

Comment: Does `send()` sends the address of the data to the kernel (i.e. value of `buffer`), or does the data is fully copied to the send buffer (and this means that the send buffer is 10+ MB in size)?

Comment: @joseph_m: The data is fully copied, so when `send` returns you can do whatever you want to the buffer. (It might not actually be copied, since the kernel could theoretically play games with the VM mapping to do a copy-on-write. But that seems like a lot of work for an unusual use case. Anyway, that would still act like a copy, as far as your program is concerned.)

Comment: As far as I know, each socket has two buffers, the send buffer and the receive buffer. Does the data in this case get sent to the send buffer? And what is the typical size of the send buffer on Windows?

Comment: (1) Yep, that's the buffer it is sent to. (Although it might be a linked list of buffers. There's no reason for the whole send buffer to be contiguous.) (2) I have no idea, and it may well vary depending on load. You might be able to find an answer to that question on MSDN; if not, you could ask it here as a more specific question (i.e., don't edit the existing question; ask a new one.)